# how to PlaySound in threads?

Tags: winapi

When I play music with Playsound for exmp. `PlaySound("XX.wav",NULL,SND_ASYNC|SND_LOOP)` if I play then another .wav file it stops this file(XX.wav).

I think this problem can be avoided with threads. But how to make it in WinApi?How Threadfunc will look like?

And How to use it when I want to stop music when  I press SPACE but I do not want to stop it when I call another PlaySound.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PlaySound()` can only play one sound at a time.  Threading will not change that.  To play multiple sounds at the same time, you need to either:

1) mix the audio frames together yourself and then push your audio buffers to `waveOutWrite()`.

2) use the playback capabilities of the [DirectSound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb318665.aspx) API.  It allows you to [mix multiple sounds together](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms804968.aspx#dx_DirectSound_Buffers_Mixing_Sounds) during playback.

I would suggest #2.